# User Writeback disabled in Azure AD Connect

Tags: azure, active-directory, synchronization

I have an On-premise Domain Controller, I want to sync all the users with Azure AD. To do so, I have used Azure AD Connect (downloaded it from the Azure portal). But recently, the User Writeback has been disabled. Can anyone provide any solution or alternative for this problem?